# Subquery and group by : Validation failed: mismatched input 'FROM' expecting <EOF>

Tags: sql, subquery, string-aggregation

I want to calculate the cost by multiplying a price with the quantity of my equipment.

My data are like that :

| idnt_eqpm | prx_tot_net | prix_pump_ht |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10954847 | 10 | 8 |

And I want this data :

| idnt_eqpm | cout_total | CA | idnt_eqpm_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10954847 | 20 | 16 | 2 |

To do that someone told me that I have to use WITH statements and subquery.

Firstly I used a count for calculate the number of my equipment for each equipment.

After I calculate a cost by multiplying a price with my count field. I try this request :

```
`SELECT
     idnt_eqpm ,
     prx_tot_net ,
     prix_pump_ht ,
     cout_total ,
     CA ,
    COUNT( idnt_eqpm ) AS  idnt_eqpm_count 
FROM (
    SELECT prix_pump_ht * idnt_eqpm_count as cout_total,
    prx_tot_net * idnt_eqpm_count as CA,
    idnt_eqpm_count 
    FROM  cat_fa_ca_equipement_bte_test 
) AS T

GROUP BY  
     prx_tot_net ,
     prix_pump_ht ,
     cout_total ,
     CA`
```

But I have this error :

```
Validation failed: mismatched input 'FROM' expecting <EOF>
```

Someone can help me, I don't know how to use subquery with aggregations ?

Comment: Could you edit your question and share some simple data and the expected output ? It's hard to help without some additional data/details

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your help, I added a example of data that I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple query using aggregate functions `sum()` and `count()` can do the trick :

```
select idnt_eqpm, sum(prx_tot_net)  as cout_total, 
                  sum(prix_pump_ht)  as CA,
                  count(idnt_eqpm) as idnt_eqpm_count
from cat_fa_ca_equipement_bte_test
group by idnt_eqpm
```

Comment: I don’t know why I didn’t think of that, it's more simple like that. Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help :)